# Multiple datasources in Grails 3 service?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I'm upgrading an application from Grails 2 to Grails 3. In the application I have a Grails service where I need to pick data source based on a url param. So my setup in Grails 2 looks sort of like this (pseudo-code):

*application.yml*:

```
development:
    dataSource_1_a
    dataSource_2_a
    dataSource_2_b
test:
    dataSource_1_a
    dataSource_2_a
    dataSource_2_b
```

*FooService.groovy*:

```
Sql getSqlInterface(Environment env) {
    switch(env){
        case Environment.A:
            return new Sql(dataSource_2_a)
        case Environment.B:
            return new Sql(dataSource_2_b)
        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid environment $env!")
    }
}
```

But in Grails 3 I have yet to manage to use two data sources in the same service (with a `dataSources` block in `application.yml`). If I call one of them `dataSource` then that one will work, but not the other one. I know that you can do `static mapping = { datasource 'secondary' }` but that also doesn't seem to support multiple data sources.

Comment: The title of your post says Grails 3, but you refer to Grails 2 in the quesiton. You might want to clarify that.

Comment: I updated the question saying I was upgrading from 2 to 3. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was this:

```
ApplicationContext context = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext

switch (env) {
    case Environment.A:
        return new Sql((DataSource)context.getBean('dataSource_1_a'))
    case Environment.B:
        return new Sql((DataSource)context.getBean('dataSource_1_b'))
    default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid environment $env!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources) you can add multiple dataSources to your domain Class.

An Service can only have one DataSource, but you could make an Service for each DataSource and one Service that manage the request, like this:

```
   switch(Environment env){
   case Environment.A:
        return dataSourceAService.method()
    case Environment.B:
        return dataSourceBService.method()
    default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid environment $env!")
   }
```

Comment: how do you specify that which service will handle which datasource? I tried using the line below, but it is not working: static datasource = 'datasource2'